# Page jsf into dialog not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I try to folow exemple from primefaces site .using Dialog Framework - Basic

```
    <p:commandButton value="Options" icon="ui-icon-extlink" action="#{dialogBean.viewCarsCustomized}" />
```

Bean DialogBean

public class DialogBean {

```
public String viewCarsCustomized() {  
    return "dialog:viewCars?modal=true";  
}
```

}

viewCars.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

    <h:head>  

    </h:head>  

    <h:body>  
        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">  
            <p:column headerText="Model">  
                <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Year">  
                <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">  
                <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Color">  
                <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />  
            </p:column>  
        </p:dataTable>  
    </h:body>  

</html>
```

this is My exemple on My Bean .
I Try like this

```
public String viewComposant(){
        return "dialog:AjoutC?modal=true"; 
    }
```

it is not working,I try to do like this .but every time error

> Impossible de trouver un cas de navigation correspondant depuis l'ID
>   de vue '/pagess/Parsing/ReacgModule.xhtml' pour l'action
>   '#{parserXls.viewComposant()}' avec le résultat
>   'dialog:/pagess/pagesComposant/AjoutC.jsf?modal=true'.

```
public String viewComposant(){
        return "dialog:/pagess/pagesComposant/AjoutC.jsf?modal=true"; 
    }
```

But When I do like this the page returend but not as I like

```
public String viewComposant(){
            return "/pagess/pagesComposant/AjoutC.jsf"; 
        }
```

Comment: Which PF version are you using? Is it the same as mentioned in the footer of the showcase page? The `dialog:` navigation outcome prefix is new since 4.0 (which is currently still in beta).

Comment: 3.5 version of primefaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *3.5 version of primefaces*

The `dialog:` navigation outcome prefix from ["Dialog Framework"](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkBasic.jsf) is introduced in PrimeFaces 4.0 and don't work in older versions.

So, you've 2 options:

1. Upgrade to PrimeFaces 4.0 (note: it's currently still in beta)
2. Use the "old" approach of `dialogWidgetVar.show()` in JavaScript or `visible="#{someCondition}` in JSF. See also [the `<p:dialog>` examples in PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogHome.jsf).

---

**Update**: as per the comment, here's how you could use it with `widgetVar` approach in JS:

```
<p:button value="Open dialog" onclick="w_dialog.show(); return false;" />
<p:dialog widgetVar="w_dialog">
    <p>Dialog's content.</p>
<p:dialog>
```

And here's how you could use the `visible` approach in JSF:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Open dialog" action="#{bean.showDialog}" update=":dialog" />
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="dialog" visible="#{bean.showDialog}">
    <p>Dialog's content.</p>
<p:dialog>
```

with

```
private boolean showDialog;

public void showDialog() {
    showDialog = true;
}

public boolean isShowDialog() {
    return showDialog;
}
```

You can if necessary move `<p:dialog>` into an include file which you include by `<ui:include>`.

Comment: Do you have example for dialogWidgetVar.show() to make it works .thank you in advance

Comment: I don't get it .I shoud make visisble="#" where .I have a page and I would to display it into dialog ,can you explain me more

Comment: Just one More question .is that dialog for booth cas is created first .or there is a test then dialog is created

Comment: By default, it's already created. If you want to postpone it to the opening, use `dynamic="true"`. See also the documentation. For future questions not related to the current question, please press `Ask Question` button (or simply do some basic research; documentation is your friend).