# jsf 2 primefaces openDialog not working?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, dialog, wizard

i am trying to use the Dialog-Framework of Primefaces, but I already stuck at the setting-up:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkBasic.jsf

Here an excerpt:

```
Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
options.put("modal", true);  
options.put("draggable", false);  
options.put("resizable", false);  
options.put("contentHeight", 320); 
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("showBundle", options, null);
```

it seems, that the method "opendialog(...)" does not exist at all.

can anyone help? How can I show up a modal xhtml-page (jsf) on a page?

I want to show a 'wizard' to update some data in a database (e.g. name, adress on first page, picture and job at second page, etc.); so i thought a modal dialog would solve that (with a "next" button). is this the right way or is there a better approach?

best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page jsf into dialog not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671678/page-jsf-into-dialog-not-working)

Comment: so does this only work in PM 4.0? i am wondering because it seems like it should work in 3.5 too...

Comment: i fogot; how can i get PM 4.0 beta? and can I load new contents to my dialog when i click on "next"? id like the user to read and check text after text, how would you do it?

Comment: Hi BalusC, the showcase doesn't tell me that it may need PM 4.0... it also doen't tell me that it works on 3.5 explicitly but all the other examples are 3.5 (i think) and on 3.5 the method "openDialog" is not available (eclipse can't find it)...

Comment: Since announcement of PF4 show case become inconsistent. I found couple of cases updated to version 4 without disclaimer. I also found one example with separate cases for PF35 and PF4.

Answer (score 28):

In faces-config.xml added:

```
<application>
   <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```