# openDialog not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf, primefaces

It seems, that I have exactly same problem as [jsf 2 primefaces openDialog not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128173/jsf-2-primefaces-opendialog-not-working), but I'm using Spring Boot and I do not know how to configure that while I have no `faces-config.xml`.

I found https://github.com/code-not-found/jsf-primefaces/tree/master/jsf-primefaces-spring-boot which I believe is a  good starter point for PrimeFaces (JSF) and Spring Boot combination.

In that project I added `data.xhtml` from [PrimeFaces Showcase - Dialog Framework > Data](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/data.xhtml) + `DFView.xhtml`.

I just had to change

```
PrimeFaces.current().dialog.openDynamic("selectCar", options, null);
```

to

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("selectCar", options, null);
```

while `org.joinfaces:jsf-spring-boot-parent:2.4.1` is using PrimeFaces 6.1 (not the latest 6.2)

When I click on *Select Car* button, my dfView.chooseCar is called, but after

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("selectCar", options, null);
```

dialog is not shown.

For simplicity, my dialog contains static text only.

**edit 1:**

I simply tried to create `faces-config.xml` in `src/main/resources/WEB-INF/` folder with content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
              version="2.2">
    <application>
        <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
        <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
        <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

but still not working...

Comment: Did you configure the dialog framework? See the PF documentation!

Comment: Very likely I didn't, I'm checking it now...

Comment: @Kukeltje there's exactly what is in linked SO question, to configure action listener, navigation handler + view handler...

Answer (score 0):

It shows that adding faces-config.xml with content from question is solution and it should be in `src/main/resources/META-INF/` folder.

I had additional problem with Spring Security, but this was solved using this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811446/384674